# Métodos sem parâmetros e com parâmetros

Tags: c, funções, parâmetros

Declaração métodos sem parâmetros:

```
void exemploDeMetodo(){
    int i;
}
```

Chamada de métodos sem parâmetros:

```
exemploDeMetodo();
```

Se eu quiser fazer um método com parâmetros é como?

É assim?

```
void exemplo(int i){
    faz algo com o i
}
```

Chamada de métodos com parâmetros:

```
int inteiro = 1;
exemplo(inteiro);
```

Se eu quiser retornar um inteiro, terei que colocar um parâmetro no método?

Comment: Isto é Java ou é C?

Comment: Exato, seria bom especificar qual das duas linguagens está utilizando, pois existem algumas diferenças que devem ser consideradas.

Comment: o exemplo está em C.

Comment: @JoseMaximilian procure sempre usar as tags corretas que ajudam definir sobre o que é seu problema para facilitar para as pessoas te ajudarem. Veja as edições feitas para entender que as perguntas devem ser o mais limpas possíveis, sem nada que não importe para a pergunta, assim ela poderá ajudar outras pessoas no futuro.

Comment: desculpe, farei na próxima vez. Sou Noob por aqui.

Comment: @JoseMaximilian é normal, o pessoal demora um pouco se acostumar com um site de **Perguntas e Respostas**. Quando pegar o jeito vai ver que é para o benefício de todos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está correto em todas suas suposições iniciais.

Para retornar um inteiro você não precisa de parâmetros. O retorno funciona de forma separada. Você **pode** ter parâmetro mas ele não tem relação direta com o retorno. O retorno é um resultado que você passa de volta para quem chamou.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int exemplo1() { return 1; }

int exemplo2(int i) { return i * 2; }

int exemplo3() {
    srand(time(0));
    return rand();
}

int exemplo4(int i) { return i > 0 ? 1 : 0; }

int main(void) {
    printf("%i\n", exemplo1());
    printf("%i\n", exemplo2(2));
    printf("%i\n", exemplo3());
    printf("%i\n", exemplo4(2));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/D2eQMt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lwamdlym-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Parameters.c).

Note que em C você sempre deve declarar o tipo do dado para tudo: variáveis, elementos de vetores, campos de estruturas, de parâmetros e claro, pode declarar o tipo das funções, que se confundem com o tipo de retorno da função. `void` significa retornar nada. E claro, `int` significa que vai retornar um inteiro.

Em C até existe como retornar valores através de parâmetros, mas isto é avançado, não se preocupe com isto até aprender outras coisas antes. Ainda não terá utilidade para você.

Comment: muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Você acertou quase tudo, só lhe faltou a parte de retornar um valor.

Uma função tem o seguinte formato:

```
tipoDeRetorno nomeDoMetodo(tipoDoParametro valorDoParametro) {
    //se o tipoDeRetorno for void não precisa retornar nada
    //caso contrário deve-se usar a seguinte notação:
    return variavelCompativelComOTipoDeRetorno;
}
```

Para fazer uma função que retorne um valor do tipo inteiro você deve trocar o `void` que você pôs no seu exemplo, assim:

```
int exemplo(int i) {
    int j = i*2;
    return j;
}
```

Perceba que você não precisa necessariamente retornar `i`, você pode retornar uma outra variável, o resultado de uma expressão ou um valor, desde que corresponda com o tipoDeRetorno.