# Diferença entre um método com retorno e sem retorno

Tags: java, método, void

Qual a diferença entre um método com retorno e outro sem retorno?

Sendo que um método sem retorno poderia ser apenas a soma de dois números, mas mesmo assim eu tenho o resultado dessa soma.

Comment: Seja bem vindo! Recomendo a leitura: [Qual a diferença - Um método com retorno e um método void?](https://www.guj.com.br/t/qual-a-diferenca-um-metodo-com-retorno-e-um-metodo-void/72091/2) , foque no trecho : "Cara o método com retorno você deve retornar o tipo especificado ou um tipo compativél, certo?
Já um método void, não retorna nada, ele apenas executa as instruções que estão no seu escopo"

Comment: Isso já foi respondido em C, mas não acho que ajuda tanto assim aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38935/101. E olha ndo um pouco mais esta talvez seja duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130990/101, mas não tenho certeza porque a pergunta não está lá muito clara.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

O método sem retorno é considerado um procedimento (*procedure*), e o método com retorno é considerado função (*function*).

O mais comum é usarmos como função e com parâmetro(s) porque um método deveria fazer algo de acordo com uma informação passada e no fim dá um resultado. Métodos privados fazem isto um pouco menos.

Aqui vale destacara a palavra resultado que é o termo correto do que você recebe, retorno é o procedimento de transporte, assim como há um diferença entre [parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), há diferença entre retorno e resultado. Retorno mesmo todo método tem, o que pode existir é um retorno sem um resultado, mas ok podemos usar o termo informalmente, só entenda o correto.

Outro ponto impostante que métodos possuem um parâmetro implícito chamado `this` (em Java, outras linguagens podem dar outro nome), então um método que aparenta não ter parâmetros tem pelo menos.

Existe o [método estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) que não tem esse parâmetro, por isso quase sempre não faz sentido ter um método estático, que no fundo é só uma função e não é um método já que método sempre passa mensagens para o objeto, sem pelo menos um parâmetro. Uma das exceções a isto é o [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) que não deixa de ser um método estático com características especiais. O construtor parece que não tem um retorno, mas tem, é que ele já é implícito e é sempre do tipo da classe que ele vai construir, não pode ser uma variação disto. Por isso algumas pessoas preferem um método estático usando um padrão de projeto [Method Factory](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) do que usar o construtor.

Mas por que geralmente um método sem retorno é um erro? Porque é comum que você queira obter um resultado daquilo, você não quer apenas mandar fazer algo e não ter um resultado, aquilo é usando em [expressões e não como *statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101). Existem dois casos onde se usa um método sem retorno:

- um deles é mudar estado do objeto, ou seja, mexer no `this` e isto é considerado ruim porque gera [efeito colateral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101), algo a ser evitado porque é a fonte da maioria dos *bugs* (por parte de quem sabe programar, caso contrário outros tipos podem ser mais prevalentes). Não quer dizer que não deva usar, mas deve ser evitado. Um caso bem típico é o [`setter`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101), que é polêmico se deveria existir, apesar de alguns manuais dizerem pra usar.
- outro é o método que gera um saída de dados, que também é um efeito colateral. Mesmo onde tem só uma saída e isto deveria ser raro e não misturar com classes de objetos de negócios, é comum termos um retorno indicando se deu tudo certo, a maior exceção a isto é escrever na tela console que não costuma como dar errado, mas isso só serve para exercícios e coisas muito básicas.

No seu exemplo quase sempre fará um método com retorno.

> Sendo que um método sem retorno poderia ser apenas a soma de dois números, mas mesmo assim eu tenho o resultado dessa soma

Aqui a pergunta não está clara. Você tem o resultado mesmo? Como? Dizer como o obteve é fundamental. Se obtém usando um método como o `println()` provavelmente está usando um método de tratamento de tela junto do objeto de negócio e isso quebra o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101). Não que isto não possa ser quebrado em um exercício ou algo extremamente simples, mas pra treinar fazer certo coisas reais é bom praticar o certo em sistemas complexos porque é isso que fará sempre. Se joga o resultado em um campo da classe eu começo me perguntar se essa classe deveria existir mesmo, será que não é uma classe complexa demais com campos artificiais só para não ter o retorno no método? O exemplo dado parece ser algo desnecessário e um método estático com retorno deve fazer o trabalho melhor. Sem contexto nem sabemos se está fazendo certo ou não e não podemos recomendar o melhor para seu caso porque não sabemos qual é o seu caso.

Se quer realmente entender tudo recomendo fortemente seguir os *links* postados, eles são importantes para conceituar certo e não aprender só a receita de bolo.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é que o método sem retorno funciona como um **serviço** e o método com retorno como uma função.

O método com retorno irá trazer para outra parte do código um valor ou objeto que poderá ser usado. Dado seu exemplo:

```
public void somaDois (int a, int b){
System.out.println(a+b);
}
```

Esse método não terá retorno: ele terá apenas a função de somar dois numeros. Portanto, o resultado da soma não está sendo utilizado em nenhuma parte do código, apenas está sendo printado no console.

```
public int somaDois (int a, int b){
return a+b;
}
```

Com o retorno desse método, você obterá um dado do tipo int contendo a soma de a+b. Você poderia usá-lo assim:

```
int resultadoDaSoma = somaDois(1,3);
System.out.println(resultadoDaSoma);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma resposta resumida:
Um método que retorna algo é necessário quando você quer buscar algum valor, como por exemplo um método *getNome*, onde está trazendo o nome do objeto.

Um método "sem retorno", é usado quando você tem a intenção de alterar algum dado no sistema mas não quer ter que dar retorno de nada, como por exemplo um método *setNome*.
Na realidade todos os métodos possuem algum retorno, porém métodos *void* retornam vazio, ou seja, nada.